# swapoff -a + why swapoff never finished

Tags: centos, rhel, kernel, disk, swap

we have rhel machines version rhel 7.2

since we want to set the kernel parameter `vm.swappiness` to 1
we need to perform `swapoff` and `swapon`

so we set the `vm.swappiness` to 1

and we performed `swapoff -a`

but after 1-2 days , still `swapoff -a` is running and not finished , seems that "memory" that located on a disk isn't completely transferring to  the memory cards

from `free -g` , we can see that consume swap is around 3-4 giga but its not decreasing from this point

I don't sure why `swapoff -a` not ended , but the other choice is to reboot the RHEL 7.2 machine , but we want to avoid machine restart

[image]

Comment: Can you show the full `free` output?

Comment: I update the question with full free -g , this is from other machine with the same case , and swapoff -a is still working after 14 hours

Comment: By posting a picture of text, you make it impossible for potential helpers on phones, or text terminals. to see your text. You make it impossible for any of us to make a local copy for investigation. Rather, [Edit] your Question, copy and paste the text into your Question, select it and use the `{}` formatting tool.

Comment: Is it possible someone has executed a `swapon` to re-enable some of the swap space?  That would not explain why the initial invocation of `swapoff` never terminated, though.

Answer (score -1):

Allocated swap space is allocated because RAM is allocated. To free swap you must stop every process that has allocated swappable memory (the default). I think that a running `swapoff -a` prevents further allocation, so restarting everything might suffice, but you might need to #comment out the `swap` line in `/etc/fstab` and reboot

Comment: `swapoff -a` _should_ also move any aolloctions in swap to physical RAM and then disconnect the swap space; this is a relatively common practice.

Comment: Yes, `swapoff` moves swapped-out pages back into memory, there’s no need to stop processes which have allocated swapped-out memory (let alone swappable memory).